# How to change CSS-classes with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, css, class, greasemonkey

I've been trying to gin up a small Greasemonkey script, that takes the content of a class and changes it to another class.
Basically it would change:

```
<ul class='user_type_1'>
```

into:

```
<ul class='administrator'>
```

But, I'm completely green to javascript & Greasemonkey, and all the research I did just left me even more confused.

Ideally I would like someone to explain in detail HOW I achieve this, instead of just handing over a script that works (though currently even that would be a help).

Answer (score 4):

This is super-easy with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (a javascript utility/library).  jQuery provides the functions [`addClass()`](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=addClass) and [`removeClass()`](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=removeClass), to make this a snap.

Here is **a complete, Firefox Greasemonkey, script** that changes that class:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Change one class into another.
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle   
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change introduced
    in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
//-- Get everything that has the class "user_type_1".
var userTypeNodes = $(".user_type_1");

userTypeNodes.removeClass ("user_type_1");
userTypeNodes.addClass ("administrator");
```