# How to add a CSS style to a specific node using Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, html, css, greasemonkey

There is a website that I visit on a regular basis.  It has been adding an additional, unnecessary, and non-functional vertical scrollbar next to the browser's vertical scrollbar.

To fix it, I want to create a user script that changes this line:

```
<main class="bucket__main">
```

to

```
<main class="bucket__main" style="overflow:hidden;">
```

How can I add `overflow:hidden` to `<main class="bucket_main">`?

Comment: Better approaches are shown in [How to change a class CSS with a Greasemonkey script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19385698/) and [How to change CSS-classes with Greasemonkey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102195/how-to-change-css-classes-with-greasemonkey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick if there is only one occurence of the class bucket__main:

```js
document.querySelector(".bucket__main").style.overflow='hidden';
```